# Android Studio, remove old AVD from list

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I want to remove old AVD from the 'Generic Phones and tablets list'

I successfully removed from the AVD manager but they continue to be present in the generic list.

As you should notice there are many Galaxy S7 profiles in the list.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is not related to avd. This is just to show you that how your layout looks with that device screen. This is also a approximation. In actual device, your layout's view looks some different but minor.

Comment: Thanks @M.Ashish but I added that values, there is a way to remove from the list?

Comment: As per my knowledge, you can remove from AVD but not from here.

Answer (score 1):

Found, we can delete unwanted ghost settings directly in the AVD Manager (but while creating a new AVD) with a simple right click:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\.android\avd and there is list of all devices you downloaded/cloned. Try to delete device from there.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Yes, this is the solution for similar answers i know, unfortunately this forlder does not contain that items at least in my case, i have  the one i want to preserve (Nexus 7, see updated picture).